# Selenium client doesn't close

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

We've just upgrade our Selenium 0.9.x to 2.17. I haven't gotten around to changing the code to use the new web driver, so we're still using

```
BrowserConfigurationOptions options = new BrowserConfigurationOptions();
options.setSingleWindow();
options.setCommandLineFlags("-trustAllSSLCertificates");

seleniumClient = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", "4444", "*iexplore", "http://localhost:8080/myapp/);
seleniumClient.start(options);
```

When my test ends, I call

```
seleniumClient.stop();
```

What happens then is that the Selenium client receives two commands:

```
selectWindow()
open(http://localhost:8080)</code></pre>
```

Finally, the browser window stays open, displaying the 404 message from my tomcat server. The stop() command makes the HttpCommandProcessor send a 'testComplete', I assume this causes the Selenium server to pass on the two command above.

For what it's worth, I'll paste the Selenium log output below. It seems that somehow the socket connection get's messed up. I see

```
Command request: testComplete.. here the 'testComplete' from the stop()
...
data from polling: json={command:"selectWindow",target:"",value:""}
...
putting command: json={command:"open",target:"http://localhost:8080",value:""}
...
waiting for data for at most 10 more s
```

So, there are the 'selectWindow' and 'open' commands, but then the connection waits for 10s, then issues a retry. What is this all about? I just want to close the browser.

Thanks Simon

```
26-01-12 12:14 PM   INFO    {SocketListener0-1} Command request: testComplete[, ] on session d76953d2f181468cab5eba9a382b6e99
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1} resetting frame group
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1} ---------retrieving CommandQueue for sel_86748
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1}     sel_86748 commandHolder sel_86748 getCommand() 
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1} putting command: json={command:"selectWindow",target:"",value:""}
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1} ..command put?: true
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} data from polling: json={command:"selectWindow",target:"",value:""}
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1}     sel_86748 commandResultHolder sel_86748 getResult() called
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0}     sel_86748 commandHolder sel_86748 getCommand() -> json={command:"selectWindow",target:"",value:""}
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1} waiting for data for at most 1800 more s
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} res to sel_86748: json={command:"selectWindow",target:"",value:""}
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handled by org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINEST  {SocketListener0-0} resetStream()
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2012 11:14:20 GMT
Server: Jetty/5.1.x (Windows 7/6.1 amd64 java/1.6.0_22
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 1048


26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} REQUEST from SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:4444:
POST /selenium-server/driver/?&localFrameAddress=top&seleniumWindowName=&uniqueId=sel_86748&sessionId=d76953d2f181468cab5eba9a382b6e99&counterToMakeURsUniqueAndSoStopPageCachingInTheBrowser=1327576460834&sequenceNumber=102 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Host: localhost:4444
Content-Length: 13
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache


26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINEST  {SocketListener0-0} Contexts at /selenium-server/driver/: [/selenium-server/driver/*=[HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]], /selenium-server/*=[HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]], /=[HttpContext[/,/]]]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Try HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver],0
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Try HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server],0
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.jetty.http.handler.SecurityHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.StaticContentHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} PATH=/driver/ RESOURCE=file:/E:/Development/_umbrella/webtest2/MISSING%20RESOURCE
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Looking for file:/E:/Development/_umbrella/webtest2/MISSING%20RESOURCE
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.SessionExtensionJsHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.SingleTestSuiteResourceHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.SeleniumHTMLRunnerResultsHandler@669a4cb
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.CachedContentTestHandler@6b541147
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} req: POST /selenium-server/driver/?&localFrameAddress=top&seleniumWindowName=&uniqueId=sel_86748&sessionId=d76953d2f181468cab5eba9a382b6e99&counterToMakeURsUniqueAndSoStopPageCachingInTheBrowser=1327576460834&sequenceNumber=102 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Host: localhost:4444
Content-Length: 13
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache


26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} ---------retrieving CommandQueue for sel_86748
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Browser d76953d2f181468cab5eba9a382b6e99/:top sel_86748 posted OK
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} ---------retrieving CommandQueue for sel_86748
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} putting command: OK
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} ..command put?: true
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1} data from polling: OK
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0}     sel_86748 commandHolder sel_86748 getCommand() called
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1}     sel_86748 commandResultHolder sel_86748 getResult() -> OK
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} waiting for data for at most 10 more s
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1} ---------retrieving CommandQueue for sel_86748
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1}     sel_86748 commandHolder sel_86748 getCommand() 
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1} putting command: json={command:"open",target:"http://localhost:8080",value:""}
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1} ..command put?: true
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} data from polling: json={command:"open",target:"http://localhost:8080",value:""}
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1}     sel_86748 commandResultHolder sel_86748 getResult() called
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0}     sel_86748 commandHolder sel_86748 getCommand() -> json={command:"open",target:"http://localhost:8080",value:""}
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1} waiting for data for at most 1800 more s
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} res to sel_86748: json={command:"open",target:"http://localhost:8080",value:""}
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handled by org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINEST  {SocketListener0-0} resetStream()
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2012 11:14:20 GMT
Server: Jetty/5.1.x (Windows 7/6.1 amd64 java/1.6.0_22
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 1061


26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} REQUEST from SocketListener0@0.0.0.0:4444:
POST /selenium-server/driver/?&localFrameAddress=top&seleniumWindowName=&uniqueId=sel_86748&sessionId=d76953d2f181468cab5eba9a382b6e99&counterToMakeURsUniqueAndSoStopPageCachingInTheBrowser=1327576461138&sequenceNumber=103 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Host: localhost:4444
Content-Length: 13
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache


26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINEST  {SocketListener0-0} Contexts at /selenium-server/driver/: [/selenium-server/driver/*=[HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver]], /selenium-server/*=[HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]], /=[HttpContext[/,/]]]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Try HttpContext[/selenium-server/driver,/selenium-server/driver],0
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Try HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server],0
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.jetty.http.handler.SecurityHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.StaticContentHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} PATH=/driver/ RESOURCE=file:/E:/Development/_umbrella/webtest2/MISSING%20RESOURCE
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Looking for file:/E:/Development/_umbrella/webtest2/MISSING%20RESOURCE
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.SessionExtensionJsHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.SingleTestSuiteResourceHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.SeleniumHTMLRunnerResultsHandler@669a4cb
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.CachedContentTestHandler@6b541147
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handler org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} req: POST /selenium-server/driver/?&localFrameAddress=top&seleniumWindowName=&uniqueId=sel_86748&sessionId=d76953d2f181468cab5eba9a382b6e99&counterToMakeURsUniqueAndSoStopPageCachingInTheBrowser=1327576461138&sequenceNumber=103 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Host: localhost:4444
Content-Length: 13
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache


26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} ---------retrieving CommandQueue for sel_86748
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Browser d76953d2f181468cab5eba9a382b6e99/:top sel_86748 posted OK
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} ---------retrieving CommandQueue for sel_86748
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} putting command: OK
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} ..command put?: true
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1} data from polling: OK
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0}     sel_86748 commandHolder sel_86748 getCommand() called
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1}     sel_86748 commandResultHolder sel_86748 getResult() -> OK
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} waiting for data for at most 10 more s
26-01-12 12:14 PM   INFO    {SocketListener0-1} Got result: OK on session d76953d2f181468cab5eba9a382b6e99
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1} Handled by org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINEST  {SocketListener0-1} resetStream()
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-1} RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2012 11:14:20 GMT
Server: Jetty/5.1.x (Windows 7/6.1 amd64 java/1.6.0_22
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 2


26-01-12 12:14 PM   WARNING {testAutocomplete.html} Single file runner completed for: testAutocomplete.html
26-01-12 12:14 PM   WARNING {watchprogress-159485824} Finished watching progress
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINEST  {SocketListener0-1} EXCEPTION 
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINEST  {SocketListener0-1} null
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} data from polling: null
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0}     sel_86748 commandHolder sel_86748 getCommand() -> json={command:"retryLast",target:"",value:""}
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} res to sel_86748: json={command:"retryLast",target:"",value:""}
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} Handled by org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumDriverResourceHandler in HttpContext[/selenium-server,/selenium-server]
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINEST  {SocketListener0-0} resetStream()
26-01-12 12:14 PM   FINE    {SocketListener0-0} RESPONSE:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 26 Jan 2012 11:14:21 GMT
Server: Jetty/5.1.x (Windows 7/6.1 amd64 java/1.6.0_22
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 1045
```

Addendum (15.3.2012):

It turns out that the RemoteControlConfiguration on the SeleniumServer was causing this behavior:

```
cfg.setReuseBrowserSessions(false);
```

solved it. Apparently the server would keep the browser open, waiting for the next test to come. I'm pretty sure there's a "right" way to close the client/server after all tests have been executed, but for my tests reusing browser sessions is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was setting

```
RemoteControlConfiguration#setReuseBrowserSessions()
```

to true when starting the SeleniumServer. Settings that property to false made everything work fine, with all browser instances closing properly.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use IEWebDriver instead and call the Quit() method on this?

```
 WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
// your code
driver.Quit();
```

Comment: I'm reluctant to rewrite my code to use WebDriver right now, but I did try this:

    seleniumClient = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(new InternetExplorerDriver(), domain);

and got the error "Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones." It seems I'd be opening a new Pandora's box going in that direction.

Comment: Try adding the following:
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
You can also change the registry settings by following the advice here:
http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1795

Comment: After adding the IE capabilities, I now get various JS errors while running the tests (Pandora's box!!). However, the browser does close in the end. The InternetExplorerDriver sends

DELETE /session/89172483-8591-4179-be7d-63cc8587d817 HTTP/1.1

which manages to close the browser. I'll see if I can convince the legacy DefaultSelenium to do the same.